# Proximity matrix in randomForest r

Tags: r, methods, random-forest

From  [this source](http://cogns.northwestern.edu/cbmg/LiawAndWiener2002.pdf) I learnt that the proximity measure of data sample i correspnding to data sample j in the `randomForest` package in R is proportion of the trees that the data i and data j end up in the same node. So, when a proximity matrix is calculated using `predict.randomForest`, if Prox(i,j)=0.993 does that mean data i and data j end up in the same node for 99.3 percent of the total number of trees in the forest model ? Can someone please explain how the proximity measure is calculated in the `predict` method in `randomForest` package ?

Thank you,
Chil.

Comment: The code is open source.

Comment: I did read the code on github. I am so sorry but since I am new to using r and not so familiar with its code structure, I couldn't understand it.

Comment: I'm going to vote as "too broad". I think SO is for more narrow questions. You have not even offered code to load the library and access a particular part of the package you have questions about, much less offered a [MCVE] that might form the basis for focussed questions about sections of code.

Comment: I don't think you can answer this question if you don't already know about this package and this algorithm. I still don't feel there is a need for an example since this is not about any problems I am having with my code. I want to know how this particular function is written to derive this particular output.  But if I ask this question in Cross Validated SE or Data science SE it will be closed as out of topic since it is about a programming language. It is so hard judging which question belongs to which site. I wish there is a better consolidated Q&A site than SE.